# fail2ban unban every ip when the server is shutting down, restoring every ban back again when newrly started

Tags: fail2ban

I have multiple jails with several thousands of banned IPs. The server was running for about a week non-stop, then when I was restarting it it took quite a long time ~2 mins to shutting down, and when the server was back on the CPU usage was unusually high.

I looked into `journalctl` and found out that `fail2ban` was unbanning all the IPs when shutting down, and restoring all of them again when newly started.

What is going on here and how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming systemd, copy `/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service` to `/etc/systemd/system` and then edit `/etc/systemd/system/fail2ban.service`, replacing

```
ExecStop=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop
```

with

```
ExecStop=/bin/true
```

However, in the future, if you want to stop fail2ban you can't use `systemctl` and will need to run `/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work; still unbanning and restoring every ban when fail2ban restarts. I copied `/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service` to `/etc/systemd/system` and replaced the `ExecStop` value as you said (I don't know what this does but `/bin/true` doesn't exist) but no change. Then I deleted the original `/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service` file but when tried to start the service, I got an error message to do `systemctl daemon-reload`. I did, the service started normally again, but still unbanning and restoring every ban.